# jQuery .load template.html in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently loading a template like this:

```
$('#mydiv').load("template1.html")
```

I'm currently using jQuery, but how can I do the same thing in pure Javascript?

Comment: You could check the jQuery source .. [letmegooglethatforyou](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.load)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using pure javascript [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) and in the `onreadychange()` event set the `innerHTML` property of `mydiv` to the contents of ajax response

```
function loadHTML(myDivId, url) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) 
        {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
               document.getElementById(myDivId).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
               var allScripts = document.getElementById(myDivId).getElementsByTagName('script');
               for (var n = 0; n < allScripts .length; n++)
               {
                   eval(allScripts [n].innerHTML)//run script inside div generally not a good idea but these scripts are anyways intended to be executed.
               }
           }
           else {
               alert('Error');
           }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

loadHTML( "mydiv", "template1.html" );
```

Comment: `load` actually execute script blocks that are added to the DOM

Comment: @Hacketo if the HTML is having script blocks and once they are set inside a div using the innerHTML, then it will automatically get loaded and executed.

Comment: no. this is not part of the spec of `innerHTML`, that's why jQuery does it by itself

Comment: @Hacketo are you saying that <script> tags inside that div will not get executed on load? I don't think that is true. Why do you think it will not get executed?

Comment: Spec say so http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0 green part

Comment: Yes, that's the only problem I'm having with it. I can insert it after on a button click for example but not when the page loads

Comment: @Hacketo got it. made the changes. thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't it load inside window.onload = init ?   function init() {
       
 loadHTML( "mydiv", "template1.html" );

    }
  
window.onload = init;

Comment: @Satch3000 use document.onload onload instead and tell me if there are any errors on the console.