# Loading div from one website to an another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I have been looking for two days a solution, without success, to display a DIV tag from one site to another.

My source website is on a server and I need to display a DIV on a local page.

i don't want to use iframe because I have to target only one text present on the source website.

Is the any solution with Java/Jquery/Html5 ?

Big thanks all :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/), and bypass CORS using a service like [CORS Everywhere](http://cors-everywhere.herokuapp.com/).

Working demo:

```js
var url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/62613919/1913729',
    selector = 'h1:first';
    
var corsUrl = 'https://cors-everywhere.herokuapp.com/' + url;

$('#result').load(corsUrl + ' ' + selector);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">Loading...</div>
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use [this solution by gurvinder372](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34331061/1913729)